# Can't Remove Anchors within FlexiGrid in IE8 using jQuery 1.5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, flexigrid, jquery-1.5

None of the methods of removal using jQuery (.remove(), .html("")) will remove an anchor or any parent of an anchor when that anchor is within a Flexigrid.

I have tried: `$("table").remove();`, `$("table").html("");`, `$("a").remove();`, `$("a").html("");` and none of these methods work.

An error is thrown in the jQuery when the anchor is being removed from the DOM every time.

I think it is because jQuery 1.5.1 uses an function that is not compatible with IE8 when it attempts to remove the anchor from the Flexigrid.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for my case.

By looping through each td within the table using standard javascript, and removing each td with standard javascript, I can remove the anchor within the td without triggering an error in IE8

I realize this solution may not be practical for all cases, but you can modify the code to loop through and only remove the td's that contain anchors.

Here is the code I use:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var tableData = container.querySelectorAll(".tableContainer")[0].getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++ ) {
    tableData[i].innerHTML = "";
}
```